# Jquery draggable - get image coordinates

Tags: jquery, position, draggable, crop

I have a div containing an image that can be dragged around inside the div to get the coordinates for the cropping of the image. I was able to get the right coordinates but as soon as I dragged the image to a certain position I cannot redrag to another position, if I don't like the detail of the image... where do I go wrong... The final positions x + y will be saved into a hidden input... here's my code:

```
    <!-- Div container 350x350px with border where detail of image can be chosen -->
<div id="draggable">
    <!-- Image (bigger than div draggable) that is draggable in the div -->
<img id="dragimg" src="<?php echo $path_to_image_directory.$filename; ?>" />
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dragimg").draggable({
            stop: function(){
                var finalxPos = $(this).css('left');
                var finalyPos = $(this).css('top');
                //  alert( "Drag stopped!\n\nOffset: (" 
                + finalxPos + ", " + 
                finalyPos + ")\n");
                $('#crop [name="finalX"]').val(finalxPos);
                $('#crop [name="finalY"]').val(finalyPos);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can you aid me in solving my issue?

Comment: I think nobody has answered this because it seems to work just fine.  I put the code in http://jsfiddle.net/b8cNk/ and it doesn't seem to have any problems for me.  Please make the fiddle break, and then we may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the absolute position in his parent is the .position()

```
$('.object').bind('drag',function(){

 var obj = $(this);
 var position = obj.position();
 var leftpos = position.left;
 var toppos = position.top;
 });
```

and you can add a input val function like

```
<input type="text" name="top" id="topVal"/>
```

and in the bind function

```
$('#topVal').val(toppos);
```